# livequery stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, livequery

```
$j(".context-menu").livequery(function(){
    alert('found');
});
```

This was working until a couple of days ago. It just suddenly stopped. On addition of new elements with class 'context-menu' nothing happens.

Although in firebug if I run the above statement, its found and an alert is thrown.

Any idea what the problem could be ?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/scripts/prototype.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/scripts/jquery-1.4.2.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/scripts/jquery.livequery.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='fun'>fun</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you don't use the built-in `.live('event', handler_function)` method?

Comment: @ThiefMaster: What I am trying to accomplish is setting a css to an match element on being rendered.

Comment: Put it in your question, not in a comment.

Comment: Yep, added it to the question

Comment: Take a look at my answer - livequery works fine for me with jQuery 1.4.4. I woudl advise you to try your code in jsfiddle and see what exactly poerevts yoru code form running. Maybe some other js error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this simple snippet to test if livequery works with current jQuery and it does with no problem (here's the jsfidde http://jsfiddle.net/x3tds/1/):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="adddiv('')">Click me</a>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://brandonaaron.net/javascripts/plugins/livequery.js"></script>


<script>

jQuery("div").livequery(function() { alert("div added") })

function adddiv()
{
    jQuery("a").append("<div>Hello</div>")
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yep. But it does not solve my problem. Since I need a callback on whenever a new element (matching my selector) has been added to the dom.

Comment: Thanks :) It worked for me. Only difference was that I was using jquery-1.4.2. May that was it :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update any of your other Javascript code? It seems like you have a syntax error or something in the rest of your Javascript which would mean that everything (including this part) fails.

Run your site with the Firebug error console active and make sure it catches Javascript errors and warnings by checking your settings (the arrow in the console tab).

Comment: Could you tell me what the error is. Since the page loads fine, without breaking. Firebug doesn't say anything either

Comment: No, not without seeing more of your code or being able to debug your site myself. Can you send me either a link or your entire Javascript-code?

Comment: To make things easier I don't have any js files that are run (other than jquery). After the page loads I run the mentioned js in firebug. Then I try document.body.appendChild(el) and it doesn't seem like livequery is being called.

Answer (score 0):

Did you recently upgrade to jQuery 1.4.2? I don't think the `livequery` plugin is fully compatible with jQuery 1.4+